# Why does my vue code not work as expected?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

there are two `components` in div,When the two `components` were rendered together, I clicked the  `button` to switch properly, but in the case of rendering only one component, the switch becomes abnormal.

this is my code

Base.vue

```js
<template>
  <div :id="id">{{msg}}</div>
</template>

<script lang='ts'>
import { Component, Prop } from "vue-property-decorator";
import Vue from "vue";

@Component
export default class Base extends Vue {
  id!: string;
  msg = "this is Base";
}
</script>
```

child.vue(no template)

```js
<script lang='ts'>
import Base from "@/components/Base.vue";
import { Prop, Component } from "vue-property-decorator";
@Component
export default class extends Base {
  @Prop({ default: "helloWorld" })
  childId!: string;
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.id = this.childId;
    this.msg = "this is Child " + this.childId;
  }
}
</script>
```

App.vue(display these components)

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Child v-show="!show" childId="child1" style="color:#f00;"/>
    <button @click="click">change</button>
    <Child v-show="show" childId="child2" style="color:#f0f;"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import Child from "@/components/Child.vue";
import Component from "vue-class-component";

@Component({
  components:{
    Child,
  }
})
export default class App extends Vue {
  show= false;
  click() {
    this.show = !this.show;
  }
}
</script>
```

[image: begin]

and click the `button` the result is

[image: click button]

These results are expected. But if all the `v-show` in the app. vue above are changed to `v-if`, the result is confusing

[image: begin after change]

then click the `button` the result is

[image: after click]

In our expectation it should display child2 here. So why does this happen?

Answer (score 2):

Your first click creates the the show-property which didn't exist because you didn't create your `data()` properly.

I'll not speculate exactly in the reasons why, but I assume there might be some funny boolean casts, and the property might not be reactive since it's not in data.  Either way, just create it and it'll work as you intended:

```
export default class App extends Vue {
  data(){ 
     return {
       show: false
     }
  },
  click() {
    this.show = !this.show;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks！！

I solved this problem when I added different keys to the two Child components

```html
<Child v-if="!show" childId="child1" key="hello1" style="color:#f00;" />
<Child v-if="show" childId="child2" key="hello2" style="color:#f0f;" />
```

I think the reason is Vue's `diff` algorithm, Vue considers these two components to be the same component

Answer (score 0):

Because when you use `v-if`, it will use the single same `Child` component. The `this.msg` will only change once in the `constructor`. The `msg` will not change when the `childId props` changed, so you need the `Watch`. When the `childId` changed, then to update the `msg`

Child.vue

```
<script lang='ts'>
import Base from "@/components/Base.vue";
import { Prop, Component, Watch } from "vue-property-decorator";
@Component
export default class extends Base {
  @Prop({ default: "helloWorld" })
  childId!: string;
  @Watch('childId')
  onChildIdChanged(val: any) {this.msg = "this is Child " + val}
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.id = this.childId;
    this.msg = "this is Child " + this.childId;
  }
}
</script>
```